# Rename Form on Load MSVisual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, forms, c++-cli, rename

Somebody have an idea how to rename form onLoad?
I tried:

```
private: System::Void General_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         String^ test = "test";
         String^ x= "General: " + test;
         this->Name = x;
         }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: How doesn't it work?  What happens?

Comment: What?  The name doesn't change? How do you know that "nothing happens"?

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint.  If it doesn't fire then you wrote an event handler but forgot to subscribe it.  A form should not listen to its own events, override the OnLoad method instead.

Answer (score 1):

I should use this->Text = x; not this->Name = x;

Comment: I really think he IS trying to change the name rather than the Text.